# How to make Emmet on Notepad++ treat extension .xslt as language XSLT?

Tags: xslt, notepad++, emmet

When file extension is .xsl everything is good, but with .xslt it falls back to default: html, so I cannot expand XSLT code.

I believe it does not look at file extension, because for whatever file, if you choose CSS as syntax highlight, you can expand CSS, eg: 'va' expands to 'vertical-align: top;'; if you choose any other syntax highlight, 'va' expands to ''.

The problem is I am already using XML syntax highlight for both .xsl and .xslt .  I tried to edit the config file C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\EmmetNPP\emmet\snippets.json but  there was just no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `langs.xml`. It has all the default associations between languages and extensions. Located in `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\langs.xml`.

Comment: Thank you, but I have associated extension .xslt to XML, and it gives what I described above.  How to configure langs.xml exactly?